# How do I test a click on SVG objects using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, svg

I am trying to write a code to check the functionality of a click on an SVG object - for example a US state on this URL

```
http://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=usa
```

This works, but is there a better way to do this? Something without physically moving the mouse?

```
robert = new Robot();
robert.mouseMove(x, y);
// full click once to get focus on the window
robert.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robert.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
// then set the filter
robert.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robert.mouseMove(x, y);
robert.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SVG, everything displayed is a block defined by coordinates. In your case, every state is a block as well and therefore has an XPath which you will be able to use in your Selenium code.

Use your browser developement tool to analyse the code of the page and find which block corresponds to the state you want to click on.

Here is the  element corresponding to California.

```
<path cs="100,100" d="M371.75,174.28l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.02l-1.09,4.03l-1.09,4.02l-1.09,4.02l-1.09,4.02l-1.09,4.02l-1.09,4.02l-1.09,4.02l-1.09,4.02l2.98,4.56l3,4.56l3.02,4.56l3.05,4.55l3.07,4.54l3.09,4.54l3.11,4.53l3.13,4.53l2.41,3.75l2.42,3.75l2.44,3.75l2.45,3.74l2.46,3.74l2.48,3.74l2.49,3.73l2.5,3.73l3.46,5.32l3.48,5.31l3.51,5.3l3.53,5.3l3.56,5.29l3.59,5.28l3.62,5.28l3.9,5.63l-0.39,1.82l0.45,2.66l1.95,5.06l0.13,1.14l0.03,0.03l-0.12,1.14l0.89,1.45l2.36,2.25l0.44,0.95l-0.01,0.07l-0.13,0.6l-0.83,0.59l-3.5,1.82l-2.02,1.65l-2.31,2.87l-0.28,2.66l-0.52,2.14l-0.76,1.62l-0.95,1.44l-1.15,1.26l-1.07,0.67l-0.98,0.09l-0.72,1.83l-0.46,3.58l0.59,2.36l1.64,1.14l0.86,1.39l0.08,1.64l-0.47,1.5l-1.03,1.37l-1.39,0.58l-2.61,-0.31l0,0l-0.11,0.19l-2.16,-0.21l-5.38,-0.65l-5.39,-0.67l-5.38,-0.69l-5.38,-0.7l-5.38,-0.72l-5.38,-0.74l-5.38,-0.76l-5.38,-0.77l-0.01,-0.15l0.44,-2.41l-0.65,-1.04l-1.22,0.26l0.24,-3.21l0.62,-1.39l0.21,-1.45l-0.19,-3.74l-1.69,-4.89l-4.56,-6.68l-2.53,-2.49l-1.78,-2.8l-1.32,-0.98l-1.81,-0.63l-0.79,0.87l-1.93,-1.21l0.94,-2.39l-1.17,-3.95l-1.57,-0.8l-4.25,-0.84l-5.11,-3.34l-1.36,-1.55l-0.04,-2.16l-2.15,-2.43l-2.98,-2.62l-2.02,-0.11l-2.43,-0.93l-3.22,-2.19l-2.03,-0.72l-4.14,-0.74l-1.44,-0.67l-0.97,-1.94l-1.29,-1.19l0.85,-1.82l0.29,-1.78l0.6,-1.28l0.15,-3.13l1.28,-2.58l-0.18,-1.11l-0.63,-0.99l-2.33,-1.86l-0.09,-1.53l0.98,-1.82l-0.33,-1.47l-1.82,-1.8l-1.25,-3.28l-2.13,-2.21l-0.34,-2.78l-1.13,-1.98l-0.15,-1.51l-2.06,-5.84l-2.58,-4.85l0.07,-2.34l0.73,-3.02l1.97,-1.4l1.24,-1.37l0.35,-1.49l0.09,-1.14l-0.71,-2.24l-4.53,-2.54L303,265.5l0.82,-3.6l-0.46,-4.07l0.68,-2.35l0.53,-2.61l1.33,-0.21l0.98,0.51l-0.41,0.98l-0.19,1.92l0.81,1.73l0.99,0.94l0.67,1.64l0.68,0.64l0.8,0.34l-0.19,-0.98l-0.31,-0.68l-0.05,-1.93l-0.42,-2.57l-0.88,-1.61l0.04,-2.45l-0.38,-0.69l-0.09,-0.94l1.5,-0.64l1.85,-0.22l2.25,0.46l6.14,2.16l1.5,-0.19l1.04,0.51l0.83,0.16l-1.52,-1.09l-1.01,-0.08l-1.08,-0.45l-2.26,-0.53l-0.83,-0.52l-0.78,-1l-0.63,-0.26l-2.42,0.63l-0.87,-0.42l-1.77,-1.99l-0.89,-0.47l-1.75,0.31l-1.18,3.25l-0.27,2.6l-0.99,-0.02l-0.76,-1.33l-1.45,-1.09l-1.06,-1.33l-1.37,-2.29l-0.8,-0.93l-1.56,1.08l0.16,-0.66l1.06,-1.48l0.69,-2.82l1.02,2.73l-0.05,-1.72l-0.79,-2.11l-0.82,-0.9l-0.31,-3.45l-2.24,-2.71l-1.33,-3.67l-3.05,-6.35l1.05,-4.41l0.06,-5.98l1.68,-2.88l0.6,-2.23l0.24,-3.58l-0.27,-2.07l-2.08,-6.11l-2.43,-4.46l0.29,-2.69l0.58,-2.62l1.49,-2.02l1.42,-2.17l0.68,-0.48l0.1,0.32l-0.3,0.47l0.44,0.31l0.52,-0.99l0.47,-0.45l-0.5,-0.24l0.16,-0.32l0.52,-0.56l2.08,-2.78l1.15,-3.98l2.69,-4.47l0.46,-1.61l0.37,-3.67l-0.06,-2.29l-0.82,-1.88l1.25,-1.95l0.61,-2.05l-0.15,-0.43l4.31,1.38l4.17,1.32l4.18,1.31l4.18,1.3l4.19,1.28l4.19,1.27l4.19,1.26l4.2,1.25l4.2,1.23l4.2,1.22l4.21,1.21l4.21,1.2l4.21,1.19l4.22,1.17l4.22,1.16L371.75,174.28zM327.88,344.91l3.35,2.08l2.11,0l0.21,0.63l-0.36,0.4l-4.66,-0.35l-1.21,-0.95l0.09,-0.83l-0.25,-0.89L327.88,344.91zM319.97,344.03l-0.97,-0.2l-1.4,-0.63l0.65,-0.36l0.91,-0.14l0.18,0.34L319.97,344.03zM324.06,347.59l-1.34,-0.04l-0.88,-0.55l-0.96,-2.47l3.3,0.61l1.15,1.27l0.12,0.3L324.06,347.59zM351.66,367.08l0.52,1.82l-1.27,-0.53l-1.4,-0.26l-0.2,-0.97l-0.11,-1.31l-0.2,-0.38l-0.92,-0.35l-0.04,-0.13l0.04,-0.61l0.34,-0.21l2.62,2.09L351.66,367.08zM330.94,365.63l-0.82,-0.17l-1.06,-0.49l-0.26,-1.31l0.93,0.16l0.8,0.38l0.43,1.09L330.94,365.63zM348.58,379.15l-1.11,-0.07l-1.07,-0.74l-0.49,-2.35l-0.7,-1.92l0.72,-0.31l0.51,1.8l1.67,2.96L348.58,379.15z" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0.5"></path>
```

---

When you have found it, right click on the  element and "Copy XPath".

```
//*[@id="chartdiv"]/div/div[1]/svg/g[7]/g/g[1]/path[47]
```

However, do it two more times and you will see that the last node is never the same.

```
//*[@id="chartdiv"]/div/div[1]/svg/g[7]/g/g[1]/path[5]
//*[@id="chartdiv"]/div/div[1]/svg/g[7]/g/g[1]/path[34]
```

So we would like to find the `<path>` in `//*[@id="chartdiv"]/div/div[1]/svg/g[7]/g/g[1]/` which the `d` attribute value starts with `M371.75,174.28l`. It should be something like:

```
//*[@id="chartdiv"]/div/div[1]/svg/g[7]/g/g[1]/path[starts-with(@d, "M371.75,174.28l")]
```

You shall have to repeat all these steps by yourself, because we might not have the same generated SVG.

---

But because [the SVG is using another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910417/xpath-given-by-chrome-devtools-could-not-be-found):

- `/g` becomes `/*[name()="g"]`
- `/svg` becomes `/*[name()="svg"]`
- `/path` becomes `/*[name()="path"]`

Which gives the following XPath:

```
//*[@id="chartdiv"]/div/div[1]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"][7]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="g"][1]/*[name()="path"][starts-with(@d, "M371.75,174.28l")]
```

---

In Selenium:

```
webDriver.findElement(
  By.xpath(
    '//*[@id="chartdiv"]/div/div[1]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"][7]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="g"][1]/*[name()="path"][starts-with(@d, "M371.75,174.28l")]'
  )
).click();
```

Comment: `title()` is dedicated to tag values (i.e. `<a>VALUE</a>`) whereas `@title` is for attribute values (i.e. `<a title="VALUE"></a>`). In your case "Montana" isn't the value of the `<a>` tag, but the value of the `title` tag attribute, so it will be `[starts-with(@title, 'Montana')]`.

Comment: That gives a NoSuchElementException. (Thank you for the help btw).

WebElement montana = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen203']/svg/a[starts-with(@title(), 'Montana')]"));

Comment: Then I get a NoSuchElementException. 
WebElement montana = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen203']/svg/a[starts-with(@title, 'Montana')]"));

Comment: Stephane, could you please help me?

Comment: Okay there is a little mystery here, give me some more time.

Comment: Found it: the `g`, `svg` and `path` elements are not detected by Selenium, you have to call them differently: `/*[name()='tagname']`. Please read my udpated post. I tried it and it works. In **your** case, the following will probably work: `WebElement montana = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen203']/*[name()='svg']/a[starts-with(@title, 'Montana')]"));`. (The site is down right now, I couldn't check)

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother you, but that still does not work :( I tried to play around with a lot of different combinations based on your answer above, but I still can't get it to work :(

Comment: I got some answers and advices on [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26910417/1515819). And here we go with a simpliest XPath query: `//*[name()='a'][@*[name()='title'][.='Alaska']]`. Tested and approved.

Comment: Stephane this works great and get's me the Alaska element, however invoking .click() on the element does not navigate the page to the next page. I see it go red (getting "clicked") but it will not navigate.

Comment: It works for me though. You will have to provide me with some more details. I don't mind if you send me your complete code, but it has to be an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Thanks

Comment: WebElement alaska = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='a'][@*[name()='title'][.='Alaska']]"));
   alaska.click();

I read on your other post that you are using Chrome, I'll try Chrome in the mean time.

Comment: It works on Chrome, does not work on Firefox, but that is fine. This fixed my issue. Thank you SO, SO *SO* much!

Comment: Ok this is strange, it works for Alaska, but does not work for say, Hawaii. Any ideas?

Comment: That's very strange indeed. I have no idea what's wrong.